# Create byte array for zip file

Tags: python, python-2.7, rpc, xml-rpc, confluence

I'm trying to import a zip file in to Confluence with the RPC importSpace object, but it keeps giving errors.. Atlassian has the following documentation that you can use for this:

public boolean importSpace(String token, byte[] importData)

I have created a small Pyhton script that loops through a file where the zip filenames are saved:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmlrpclib
import time
import urllib
confluence2site = "https://confluence"
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(confluence2site + '/rpc/xmlrpc')
username = ''
password = ''
token = server.confluence2.login(username, password)
loginString = "?os_username=" + username + "&os_password=" + password
filelist = ""
start = True

with open('exportedspaces.txt') as f:
    for file in f:
        try:
            print file
            f = open(os.curdir+ "\\zips\\" + file, 'rb')
            fileHandle = f.read()
            f.close()
            server.confluence2.importSpace(token, xmlrpclib.Binary(fileHandle)) 
        except:
            print file + " failed to restore"
            failureList.append(file)
```

Where does it goes wrong?

Comment: What is this function signature: `public boolean importSpace(String token, byte[] importData)` have to do with anything? That looks like it comes from Java...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Confluence auto-generates XMLRPC API calls as java method wrappers, hence the method signatures for the remote calls [are  specified](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/deprecated-apis/confluence-xml-rpc-and-soap-apis/remote-confluence-methods) as Java method signatures

Comment: So, one possibility is that `file` includes a trailing newline, which is messing up your call to `f = open(os.curdir+...)`. So try using `file.strip()` in that call.

Comment: You catch all exceptions.... if you are getting one, do `except Exception as e:` and then print `e` to get a better hint of the problem.

Comment: You could add `raise` to the end of the exception block to reraise the exception so we can see the stack trace. Or do `import traceback;traceback.print_exc()` to see it.

Comment: My apologies. I'm getting the following execption: name 'os' is not definied. So probably should try the solution of @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DannyvandenBerg Well, I think you'll need to do that anyway, but your error message clearly states that `os` is not defined, which makes sense, because you never `import os`

Comment: Yes, you are right. For loop fixed, importing spaces not still. I'm getting a <Fault 0: 'java.lang.Exception: com.atlassian.confluence.rpc.RemoteException: Could not import space'>